# how to show admob ads in xamarin.forms project?

Tags: xamarin.forms

how to show admob ads in xamarin.forms project?
I use using Android.Gms.Ads.Interstitial.
But Could not pass build.
I use android 11 phone.
Than you very much.

my code below:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Gms.Ads;
using Android.Gms.Ads.Interstitial;

namespace quPlayer.Droid
{
    public class MyInterstitialAd : InterstitialAd
    {
        /*
        private Context context;
        public MyInterstitialAd(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }
        */

        public string IdValue { get; set; }

        public MyInterstitialAd(string IdValue)
        {
            this.IdValue = IdValue;
        }

        public override string AdUnitId => IdValue;
        //public override string AdUnitId => throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        public override FullScreenContentCallback FullScreenContentCallback { get => throw new System.NotImplementedException(); set => throw new System.NotImplementedException(); }
        public override IOnPaidEventListener OnPaidEventListener { get => throw new System.NotImplementedException(); set => throw new System.NotImplementedException(); }
        public override ResponseInfo ResponseInfo => throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        public override void SetImmersiveMode(bool p0)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
        public override void Show(Activity p0)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Could not pass build" - what does this mean?  Are you getting error or exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a control and do that with custom renderer.

Custom control:

```
public class AdControlView : View
{
}
```

Custom renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AdControlView), typeof(AdViewRenderer))]
namespace App14.Droid
{
public class AdViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<AdControlView, AdView>
{
    public AdViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }
    string adUnitId = string.Empty;
    //Note you may want to adjust this, see further down.
    AdSize adSize = AdSize.Banner;
    AdView adView;
    AdView CreateNativeAdControl()
    {
        if (adView != null)
            return adView;

      
        adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6xxxxxxx"; //you could create you own unit id.
        adView = new AdView(Forms.Context);
        adView.AdSize = adSize;
        adView.AdUnitId = adUnitId;

        var adParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WrapContent, LayoutParams.WrapContent);

        adView.LayoutParameters = adParams;

        adView.LoadAd(new AdRequest
                        .Builder()
                        .Build());
        return adView;
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<AdControlView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control == null)
        {
            CreateNativeAdControl();
            SetNativeControl(adView);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Create your own application id and unitid or you could get the test ads on Google Admob.